# Multiple attribute queries in Apache Lucene

Tags: java, apache, lucene

The below program satisfies the query where title has both lucene and action. If I want to search for a tupple where isbn (considering isbn is not unique) is 1234 and title contains both Lucene and dummies. Does lucene provide a facility for that.

```
 StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);
 Directory index = new RAMDirectory();

IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40, analyzer);

 IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
addDoc(w, "Lucene in Action", "193398817");
 addDoc(w, "Lucene for Dummies", "55320055Z");
 addDoc(w, "Managing Gigabytes", "55063554A");
  addDoc(w, "The Art of Computer Science", "9900333X");
   w.close();

 private static void addDoc(IndexWriter w, String title, String isbn) throws IOException {
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new TextField("title", title, Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new StringField("isbn", isbn, Field.Store.YES));
 w.addDocument(doc);
 } 


String querystr = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "lucene AND action";
Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40, "title", analyzer).parse(querystr);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head ,  your `QueryParser` class is built to query the `title` field only, so in order to make a query that targets both `title` and `isbn` fields you have to make use of a class like `MultiFieldQueryParser` and a query like `title:(lucene AND dummies) AND isbn:1234` or just build your `BooleanQuery` (this is what you end up with) by hand from multiple `TermQuery` objects .

I hope this helps